# php comparing value if more than

Tags: php, session

This is current code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['clicks']) && $_SESSION['clicks']== "2" )
```

and `echo 'my messege'`

How to keep showing my message if the value more than > 2

for example 2 3 4 5 6 7 8...

I try

```
if(isset($_SESSION['clicks']) && $_SESSION['clicks']> "2" )
```

Nothing work.

Comment: Do you mean `>= 2` / `> 1` ?

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['clicks']) && $_SESSION['clicks']> 2 ), compare with integer value not string

Comment: thanks @Funk Forty Niner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['clicks']) && $_SESSION['clicks']>=2 ){
    echo 'my messege';
}
```

If you want to show the message for value 2 as well. Also try to use integer and not string when you want to compare it with an int value cause you may have issues in the future.

Comment: ouch this is true.